# How to iterate through every SECOND element of doubly linked list (ring)?

Tags: c++, iterator, doubly-linked-list

RING- linear data structure in which the end points to the beginning of the structure. It is also called a circular buffer, circular queue, or cyclic buffer.

I got a function to write. It's purpose is to produce another RING structure from the original RING, but it has its length defined and the thing is that it has to be every SECOND element of the original RING.

Example:

originalRing= 1,2,3,4,5

function newRing is called: newRing (originalRing, nRing, len1=5)

nRing=1,3,5,2,4

(explanation: '1' is the 1st element of the RING. Every second means I take 3, 5... but this is RING, so it goes like 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,... The function says nRing must have length of 5, so I am taking next every element: 2,4. Finally it gives 1,3,5,2,4)

I am using iterators (I have to, school project).

```
iterator i1 = nRing.begin(); //--- .begin() points to the 'beginning' of the Ring
if (originalRing.isEmpty()){ //---whether originalRing is empty or not
  return false;}

if (originalRing.length()==1){ //--- if originalRing no. of elements is 1, returns that Ring
  return originalRing;
}
if (len1<=0) //--- doesnt make sense
{return false;}

if(!i1.isNULL()) //--- checks whether iterator is null
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < len1; i++)
        {
            nRing.insertLast(i1.getKey()); //insert the element to the end of the Ring
            i1++;

        }
    }
```

So here, the thing I am asking is that i1++ --- it iterates elements one by one.

My question is how to define a loop with the iterator defined to have every 2nd element attached ?

Comment: What is a ring? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Not knowing exactly what you mean by "ring", `i % ring.length()` will always give you the proper index within the ring, regardless of the value of `i` and the length of the loop.  So maybe you should write your loop with that in mind?

Comment: Ive just wrote what the RING is.

Comment: How did you get [1,3,5,2,4] from [1,2,3,4,5]? Now I see, it is a circular queue.

Comment: @Croppi _it has to be every SECOND element of the original RING_ I guess.

Comment: if you know how to increment once you can also increment twice: `++(++it)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::stable_partition` to do this. It'll divide the elements in your ring buffer so that those for which the lambda returns true comes before those elements for which it returns false. You can create a stateful/mutable lambda to toggle true/false for each iteration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    // std::vector
#include <algorithm> // std::stable_partition

int main() {
    std::vector<int> RING = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for(const auto& v : RING) std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {

        std::stable_partition( RING.begin(), RING.end(),
            [toggle = false](const auto&) mutable {
                return toggle ^= true; // false becomes true and vice-a-versa
            }
        );

        for(const auto& v : RING) std::cout << v << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 3 5 2 4
1 5 4 3 2
1 4 2 5 3
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing to do is to put into the loop:

i1++;

i1++